# MySQL MULTIPLE INSERT get rows that fail?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm a beginner with PDO and MySQL, so here's my question :

How can I be sure that when performing an `INSERT .. SELECT` (or MULTIPLE `INSERT`)
all data will be inserted in database?

I know there is a rowCount() function but the number of rows inserted is dynamic.
The only way I see would be to make a `SELECT count(*)`, and then compare it with the rowCount(), but I'm not sure I'm doing it the right way.

And if not all data were inserted, is it possible to get rows which didn't work?

Also, is it possible that a SELECT query fails and retrieves only a few part of the data? (ex : It must retrieve 1000 rows but due to some failure, it retrieves 700) Or it's all or nothing?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: When executing a prepared statement, the function will [either return true of false](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php#refsect1-pdostatement.execute-returnvalues). False meaning the query didn't work as expected. You can pick it up from there and do what you want (like log the query that failed).

Comment: I know that, maybe it wasn't clear, but the real question is in the title. Is it possible to get the rows that failed (apparently not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I be sure that when performing an INSERT .. SELECT (or MULTIPLE INSERT) all data will be inserted in database?

You should [tell PDO to throw an exception](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#errors) in case of error and thus there will be a PHP error in case of a failed query.

> I know there is a rowCount() function

Row count has nothing to do in your case.

> And if not all data were inserted, is it possible to get rows which didn't work?

It is advised to redo all the successful yet queries instead. To do so you have to wrap your inserts in a **transaction**.

However, if you want to keep alll the previous inserts in place, you may wrap execute call in a try and catch operator and do whatever workaround inside.

> Also, is it possible that a SELECT query fails and retrieves only a few part of the data?

No.

Comment: The docs say: _"PDOStatement::rowCount() returns the number of rows affected by the last DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement executed by the corresponding PDOStatement object. "_ Doesn't that mean that `rowCount` in fact should return the rows affected?

Comment: It does. But it's useless if you need to know whether a query were successful or failed. To know this one, one should handle the error.

Comment: The fact is that I want to use a cron job to do it.
It insert all data in my table, and then select all rows from this table to do my job.

So, yes, I would like to keep all inserts despite not all were inserted, to treat as much data as possible.
And even if no data were inserted I want to keep executing my script.

So, the good way would be to log errors and perform a manual update with transaction if something failed?
Knowing that there is no matter of duplicate, I check it in my query.

Comment: Why do you think some of the queries will fail?

Comment: Actually I don't really know why it could fail (knowing there is no duplicate constraint).
The only thing I see would be a problem with the server, but it would stop all the script.

The fact is I'm a real beginner and I probably want to avoid and handle all possible errors. And obviously I'm wrong.

So I think you're right, there is no apparent reason that the request fails.

Comment: Just wrap it in a transaction and let PHP to lorg errors. Once it failed, there will be an entry in the error log and you will know that the whole batch have to be re-inserted after fixing the problem.